# Loading HTTP resource in Visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, http

Is there a way to allow loading of non secure resources from external sites in Visualforce pages? Below is the scenario I have.

I am creating a force.com site page. The template I received for the page references CSS and JS files hosted on non secure server. They can't be accessed using https url. Using the same URL in VF page gives error as it is unable to load the resources.

Next, I uploaded the resources as static resource in Salesforce.  However, it seems that the resources internally also reference non secure resources thus giving an error.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible to move the CSS and JS files onto a secure server?

Comment: Can you move internally referred resources into static resources? This will also help with the faster page load times

Comment: I checked with the client and it was not possible.